# How can we make an application appear on Google Play when searching for its name in multiple languages

Tags: android, google-play, locale, google-play-console

We have submitted an application to Google Play app store. Its name in English is Practical Value and in Portuguese is Valor Prático. We provided details both in English and Portuguese in the Google Play Console. The application appears with the English name Practical Value when the device language is set to English and the Portuguese name Valor Prático when the device language is set to Portuguese.

If we search for Practical Value, the application appears in Google Play search results. But if we search for Valor Prático or even just valor pratico (no accents), it does not appear in the search results.

Is it possible to make the application appear in Google Play search results using either the English or the Portuguese name so users of either language can find it?

Comment: You can simply add your translated application language in english text so where ever user search for translated text then your application will be there in list.

Comment: Thank you Ankit but I am not sure if I understood what you are suggesting.

The application text and name are both in English and Portuguese either in the code and in the Google Play Console. Still when we search for it with using the Portuguese name (Valor Prático), it does not appear in the application list search results on the Google Play application.

It appears when we search for its English name (Practical Value) though. You may try searching yourself in Google Play to see what I mean.

Do you know how to make it appear when searching for both Portuguese and English names?

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply wait, because it may take quite a long time until your app is positioned well for a given location and phrase (even weeks or months). As for app description you can try the recent "Store listing experiments" feature. And always be sure you provide a unique app name and description.